# How can I send Multiple Array in FormData API with React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native, form-data

> Form data that I want to send.
> these array will increase if user select more data
>
> what I need to do is , when user select YES it will add an array and
> when user select multiple YES it will adds multiple array.
> [image: FormData Picture]

```
    categories[65][sub_category_id]:65
    categories[65][value]:1
    categories[65][category_id]:61
    categories[65][sub_category_name]: Cover Immersion

    categories[66][sub_category_id]:66
    categories[66][value]:1
    categories[66][category_id]:61
    categories[66][sub_category_name]: Foam Immersion Support & Structure
```

[!FormData Picture with API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49MuU.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49MuU.png)

> When user select yes it adds a new array in the categories just like I
> mentioned above.
> [image: Mobile screen]
>
> well I need to send this data with FormData I already used APPEND and
> PUSH in my code but it didn't work for me maybe I didn't wrote it
> correctly.

> Full FORMDATA data
> [image: FormData DATA of api]
> this type of response I get when I hit the FORMDATA API from post man

```
"data": {
            "categories": {
                "65": {
                    "sub_category_id": "65",
                    "value": "1",
                    "category_id": "61",
                    "sub_category_name": "Cover Immersion"
                },
                "66": {
                    "sub_category_id": "66",
                    "value": "1",
                    "category_id": "61",
                    "sub_category_name": "Foam Immersion Support & Structure"
                },
                "67": {
                    "sub_category_id": "67",
                    "value": "1",
                    "category_id": "61",
                    "sub_category_name": "Foam Depth"
                }
            },
            "audit": {
                "site": "Neuro. ios22",
                "ward_id": "14",
                "score_threshold": "33",
                "super_user_id": 15,
      }
        }
```

> this is my code in expo snack for further edition
> [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/array-formdata-api)